# How is the value returned from the function SumOfLongRootToLeafPath

Tags: python, data-structures, binary-tree, recursive-datastructures

I was solving some problems on Binary tree and I got stuck in this question https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sum-nodes-longest-path-root-leaf-node/
I am using python to solve the question
I understood the logic of the solution given on the link but my question is how did the value of maxSum change in the SumOfLongRootToLeafPathUtil(root) function when nothing is returned from SumOfLongRootToLeafPath() function
how is the original value of the varaible change please help
ps:Please refer to the python code given in the link

Comment: Can you post the relevant code here please, that link may die thus making this question useless in the future.

Comment: The value is changed in a list object which is mutable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The maxSum list object passed into the `SumOfLongRootToLeafPath` function is mutable. So, when it is changed within that function, the `SumOfLongRootToLeafPathUtil` function will see the changes to it. So, there is no need to return a value.

e.g. showing mutable nature of a list

```
def change_it(value):
    value[0] = 12 # modify the list without creating a new one

value = [4]
print(value) # this will show [4]
change_it(value)
print(value) # this will show [12] as change_it has altered the value in the list
```

If a tuple had been used for maxSum rather than a List, then it would be necessary to return the result from `SumOfLongRootToLeafPath` as tuples are immutable.

e.g. showing immutable nature of a tuple

```
def change_it(value):
    value = (12, ) # can't modify the tuple, so create a new one

value = (4, )
print(value) # this will show (4,)
change_it(value)
print(value) # this will still show (4,) as change_it cannot modify the tuple
```